# Saving Data using Entity Framework Code First

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0, entity-framework-6

I am using ASP.NET MVC Razor Entity Framework Code First C#

Class - A

```
public class Om_Category
{
    [Key]
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }
    public String CategoryName { get; set; }
    public String CategorySanitized { get; set; }
    public Boolean IsActive { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }
}
```

Class - B

```
public class Om_CategorySkills
{
    [Key]
    public Int32 SkillID { get; set; }
    public String Skill { get; set; }
    public String SkillSanitized { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }
    public Boolean IsActive { get; set; }

    public Om_Category Category { get; set; }
}
```

> When I try to create the record for table Om_CategorySkills. It says
>   cannot save the duplicate value in Om_Category table.

This is happening because I am sending the Om_Category class object in Om_CategorySkills class object because there are some fields in Om_Category class that are mandatory.

So I am passing the Om_Category class object also in Om_CategorySkills class object. Is there any way to fix this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Your navigation properties doesn't seem to be right.. Can you try (I didn't test),

```
public class Om_Category
{
    [Key]
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }
    public String CategoryName { get; set; }
    public String CategorySanitized { get; set; }
    public Boolean IsActive { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }

    public virtual Om_CategorySkills CategorySkills{ get; set; }
}


 public class Om_CategorySkills
 {
     [Key]
     public Int32 SkillID { get; set; }
     public String Skill { get; set; }
     public String SkillSanitized { get; set; }
     public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }
     public Boolean IsActive { get; set; }

     public int CategoryID {get;set;}
     public virtual Om_Category Category { get; set; }
 }
```

Comment: One category can have multiple skills and one skill will have one category

Answer (score 0):

I see that your `Om_CategorySkills` object is lacking an `Int32 Om_CategoryId` property to be used as foreign key. I would also add a virtual modifier to the navigation property `Category`, in order to allow for lazy loading.

I think that it may be the case that the category object in your new/edited skill is already in the database, but was not the one retrieved by the context, so the context believes you are trying to save a new category with the Id of an existing one.

You should not try to save a skill object with a category object with no changes. Otherwise, the category object should be the one attached to the context.